# How to include measurement errors in numpy.polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

The documentation [HERE](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) for numpy.polyfit defines the optional input vector **w** as the "weights to apply to the y-coordinates". This definition is unclear and does not seem the standard definition for the weights in least-squares fits (see e.g. [HERE](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section4/pmd432.htm)).

How does one calculate the weights to use in numpy.polyfit, in the common situation where one has the 1σ error (standard deviation) of the input measurements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

The relation between **w** and the 1σ errors in numpy.polyfit is

`w = 1/sigma`

which is different from what everybody will expect.

**Edit:** following my comment on Github, the [numpy.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) 1.16 documentation now explicitly states "use 1/sigma (not 1/sigma**2)" to avoid people thinking there is a typo in the formula.

## Explanation

In least-squares fitting one generally defines the weights vector in such a way that the fit minimizes the squared error (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares) or [NIST](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section4/pmd432.htm))

`chi2 = np.sum(weights*(p(x) - y)**2)`

In the common situation where the 1σ errors (standard deviations) "sigma" are known one has the familiar textbook relation where the weights are the reciprocal of the variance

`weights = 1/sigma**2`

However the numpy.polyfit documentation defines the weight as "weights to apply to the y-coordinates". This definition is not quite correct. The weights apply to the fit residuals, not only to the y-coordinates.

More importantly, looking at the math in the Numpy (v1.9.1) code it appears that the Numpy code solves the linear problem below in the last-squares sense, where the **w** vector does indeed multiply the y-coordinate

`(vander*w[:, np.newaxis]).dot(x) == y*w`

But solving the above array expression in the least-squares sense is equivalent to minimizing the expression below with **w** inside the parenthesis

`chi2 = np.sum((w*(vander.dot(x) - y))**2)`

Or, using the notation of the Numpy documentation

`chi2 = np.sum((w*(p(x) - y))**2)`

in such a way that the relation between **w** and the 1σ errors is

`w = 1/sigma`

which is different from what everybody will expect.